# How to calculate the frequency of items sold per client?

Tags: python, frequency

I am trying to calculate the frequency of items sold for each client of my dataset BUT I don't want to calculate the frequency on the length of the whole dataset but on the total number of purchased items per client.

My dataframe would look like this:

```
data = {'ClientId': ['1','2','3','4','2','2','1','4'],
        'QuantitySold': ['5','10','6','7','5','10','8','7']
       }
```

Expected output:

```
Client Id     QuantitySold     FrequencySold
1             5                0.385
2             10               0.4
3             6                1
4             7                0.5
2             5                0.2
2             10               0.4
1             8                0.615
4             7                0.5
```

Calculation explained: for client 1 = 5/(5+8)= 0.385

How can I do that using Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a dictionary with the totals for each client, then just divide the current quantity by those totals:

```
import collections
totals = collections.defaultdict(int)
for c, q in zip(data["ClientId"], data["QuantitySold"]):
    totals[c] += int(q)
# defaultdict(int, {'1': 13, '2': 25, '3': 6, '4': 14})

for c, q in zip(data["ClientId"], data["QuantitySold"]):
    print(c, q, int(q)/totals[c])
```

Output:

```
1 5 0.38461538461538464
2 10 0.4
3 6 1.0
4 7 0.5
2 5 0.2
2 10 0.4
1 8 0.6153846153846154
4 7 0.5
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution appears to be working. However, I am not sure how to add the frequency column to my dataset from the loop

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

  # Please be carefull about the data ==>  '5','10' and 5,10 are different (str /int)!

data = {'ClientId': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '2', '2', '1', '4'],
        'QuantitySold': [5, 10, 6, 7, 5, 10, 8, 7] }                # <=== Without ''
        


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df['total sales'] = df['QuantitySold'].groupby(df['ClientId']).transform('sum')

df['frequency'] = df['QuantitySold']/df['total sales']
```

The first row creates a new column 'total sales' using the `transform` method, `groupby` I think more easy to follow. And the second row adds one more column 'frequency' to existing data frame and calculates the frequencies with a simple divide operator.

Output (tested , pasting here directly from the terminal):

```
   ClientId  QuantitySold  total sales  frequency
0         1             5           13   0.384615
1         2            10           25   0.400000
2         3             6            6   1.000000
3         4             7           14   0.500000
4         2             5           25   0.200000
5         2            10           25   0.400000
6         1             8           13   0.615385
7         4             7           14   0.500000
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Hi, @donald-duck , i just hoped it is clear ,But you are right. I may add:   First row from the code creates a new column 'total sales'  using the transfrom method , groupby I think more easy to follow.                                                                         and  second row adds one more column 'frequency' to existing data frame and calculates the frequencies with simple divide operator..                                                       Ps : I am still having difficulties to format SO comments, sorry.

Comment: @​everyt4u You were supposed to edit that into your answer, but it's OK, I copied your comment into your answer.

Comment: Actually that doesn't work for my problem because the 'total sales' is for the whole dataset, while I'm trying to have 'total sales' per client Id and then divide that by 'QuantitySold'

Comment: @DonaldDuck Thank you, appreciated..I have also added the output.Still new, here..

Comment: Dear @killimandjaro from my code ' total sales' are not for whole dataset , It is still still per client..I have added the output for you..I think you are missing the data format in your dictionary..Just copy and run the code , you will see it is working.I hope it helps .

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas`,

Get the totals and convert to a `dict`:

```
summed = df.groupby('ClientId').sum('QuantitySold')
sums = summed.to_dict()['QuantitySold']
```

To compute the freq for each row:

```
def get_freqs(row):
    return row[1] / sums[row[0]]
```

Apply to every row:

```
df['FrequencySold'] = df.apply(get_freqs, axis=1)
```